# Continuing a script after Ctrl + C

Tags: bash, controls

I'm working on a bash script to test access points. To end **sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 && sudo airodump-ng mon0** -- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> needs to be pressed, this cancels the entire script, instead of continuing. How can I get it to continue after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>?

```
# Stop Services To Fix Conflicts
service network-manager stop
service avahi-daemon stop
killall wpa_supplicant
clear

# Scan For Access Points
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 && sudo airodump-ng mon0

# Restart Networking Services
sudo airmon-ng stop wlan0
sudo aitmon-ng stop mon0
sudo service network-manager start
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set up a trap, like this:

```
int_trap() {
    echo "Ctrl-C pressed"
}


trap int_trap INT

echo "Enter line or press Ctrl-C"

xterm

echo "Continuing the script"
```

See the `bash` manpage for more info and usage examples in e.g. /usr/bin/bashbug. Be careful however, the traps may prevent your script from exit cleanly when it's really needed